# Best way to load images in LongListSelector in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am in tough situation. where I want to create infinite scrolling list of images.size of images are 200 x 200.
I am using LongListselector images should be loaded from the remote urls.So what is the best way of loading images in LongListselector.
Below is the xaml of LongListSelector Item.

```
<Image  Width="190" Height="130"  Source="{Binding Image}"   ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed"/>
```

Below is the viewmodel

```
public class RemoteImage{
public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                this._image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ItemCommon._baseUri, this._imagePath));                return this._image;
            }

            set
            {
                this._image= value;
                this.SetProperty(ref this._image, value);
            }
        }
}
```

But above implementation gives me Out Of Memory Exception.
Can anyone guide me how to load images in infinite scrolling LongListSelector without getting out of memory exception.

Thank You.

Comment: You're probably loading many images and exceed the memory limit each app has available to use.

Comment: Yes you are right but How to solve this.I want to minimize memory usage please suggest best techniques to do it.

Comment: Youy should load a number of images that don't exceed the memory limit. Let's say 100 images for instance. Each time you scroll to the bottom or top (since you want to implement infinite scrolling) of your control, you should load the next/previous 100 images.

Comment: Above shown code automatically loads the images. I am not loading images.Can you please suggest how can I implement your idea.

Comment: Isn't your RemoteImage class a property of you binding source class? This binding source class must not exceed the memory limit. So limit the items you load each time. Then when you scroll to the bottom or top do what I previously suggested.

Comment: Hey pantelis I want something like Picasso(http://square.github.io/picasso/) Image loading library used in android apps.Can you guide me to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library. What does it do?

Comment: It fetches the images from remote server. Creates bitmaps and then sets the bitamp onto imageview.

Comment: Yeah well, thats the general idea, but how does it manage memory usage? Do you know how the ImageView recycling is handled?

Answer (score 1):

Load more items as the user scrolls down, and approaches close to the end of list.
Check [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e)

Comment: I do not want infinite scrolling logic.I know how to do it.I want to reduce the memory footprint of the app since there are lot of bitmaps will be created when User goes on scrolling.